# How to get data from activation link with Java Servlet

Tags: java, email, gwt, servlets

I am using GWT and after that a user registers, I need to send the user a mail with an activation link.

The activation link might contain the username of the user and a hashed value.

With PHP, I know to retrieve these values using get method.

I am new GWT Java and I want to be able to get the values in the activation link. I am also using a Java on the server.

I just want to know, what i need to do when the user is redirected to my site after clicking on the activation link (which contains some data to identify the user).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with GWT. When the user clicks the activation link, a servlet of yours is invoked. For example, you have a servlet mapped to `/useractivate`, and your URL is `http://yoursite.com/useractivate?hash=4342bc322&user=foo`.

Then in the `doGet()` method of your servlet you need to call:

```
String hash = request.getParameter("hash");
String user = request.getParameter("user");
// .. handle activation
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also call `HTTP.GET` method in GWT with `RequestBuilder`. Have a look at [RequestBuilder.GET](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html#GET) and [its usage](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHttpRequests)

I think it will be helpful to you and I advise you to look at [similar topic - making http request in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272158/how-to-respond-if-possible-to-http-get-requests-in-gwt)

From GWT tutorial :

```
import com.google.gwt.http.client.*;
...

String url = "http://www.myserver.com/getData?type=3";
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode(url));

    try {
      Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
           // Couldn't connect to server (could be timeout, SOP violation, etc.)
        }

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
          if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
              // Process the response in response.getText()
          } else {
            // Handle the error.  Can get the status text from response.getStatusText()
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
      // Couldn't connect to server
    }
```